# MvvmCross Tab navigation raises exception Trying to show a tab without a TabBarViewController, this is not possible

Tags: tabs, navigation, mvvmcross

I'm trying to create tab navigation in iOS project using latest MvvmCross 5.x., but I'm getting the exception saying: 
**"Trying to show a tab without a TabBarViewController, this is not possible!"**

Can anyone explain, what could be wrong, or is there any example simple project to show how tab navigation works using new latest MvvmCross 5.x version in **iOS** projects?

This is my code:

```
[Register("MainView")]
[MvxRootPresentation(WrapInNavigationController = true)]
public class MainView : MvxTabBarViewController<MainViewModel>
{

}


[MvxTabPresentation]
public partial class HomeView : MvxViewController<HomeViewModel>
{
}

public class IosViewPresenter : MvxIosViewPresenter
{
    public override void Show(IMvxIosView view, MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        // This line gets called, but raises exception complaining that TabBarController is null.
        base.Show(view, request);
    }
}

[Register ("AppDelegate")]
public class AppDelegate : MvxApplicationDelegate
{   
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
    {
        Window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);

        var setup = new Setup(this, Window);
        setup.Initialize();

        var start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
        start.Start();

        setup.EnsureInitialized(GetType());

        Window.MakeKeyAndVisible();

        return true;
    }
}

public class Setup : MvxIosSetup
{
    protected override IMvxIosViewPresenter CreatePresenter()
    {
        var viewModelLoader = new MvxViewModelLoader();
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxViewModelLoader>(() => viewModelLoader);

        var presenter = new IosViewPresenter((MvxApplicationDelegate)ApplicationDelegate, Window, viewModelLoader);
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxIosViewPresenter>(presenter);

        return presenter;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to navigate to MainView before you navigate to HomeView

Comment: So instead of using:
var start = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxAppStart>();
      start.Start();
which should do the navigation to MainViewModel, I should point IMvxAppStart to something like FirstViewModel, and then inside of FirstViewModel navigate to MainViewModel. Is that what you are proposing?

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue, so I decided to add the MvvmCross class libraries directly to debug and see what was going on. Strangely enough, at that point I no longer had this issue. The presenter correctly stored a reference to the tab bar controller, which is necessary when presenting tabs.